# Using GROUP BY with AVG functions - incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, group-by, syntax-error, average

```
SELECT 
    AVG (CASE 
            WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '-%' 
               THEN NULL
            WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '0%' 
               THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST (ItemPrice AS FLOAT) 
         END)
GROUP BY 
    HHIncome 
FROM 
    Tacos
```

SQL is returning the following error:

> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>   SQLState:  S0001
>   ErrorCode: 156

Can someone explain why, on its own, the statement above is incorrect, but is operable when nested in the statement below?

```
SELECT  
    HHIncome AS Income_Segment, 
    COUNT(Customer) AS number_of_customers, 
    AVG (CASE 
            WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '-%' THEN NULL
            WHEN ItemPrice LIKE '0%' THEN NULL
            ELSE CAST (ItemPrice AS FLOAT) 
         END) AS avg_item_price, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(ReceiptIDDesc)) AS number_of_orders, 
    SUM(CAST(ItemPrice AS FLOAT)) AS total_spend
FROM
    Tacos 
GROUP BY 
    HHIncome;
```

Comment: `FROM` needs to be before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: On your first query, you put `FROM` after `GROUP BY` so it generates error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of the GROUP BY and FROM clauses. GROUP BY needs to be after FROM [Table Name].

Comment: Right... Thank you!